# During TDD how to test following scenarios

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, moq

Trying to adopt TDD for development but there are some scenarios in which I was out of best options, how to write the code and test them.

Following are the code scenarios:

1. There is a public method say Initialize(), it initializes only private members of class. How to test this method if it is working fine or not.
2. There is a private method say DoSomething() and is being called by 2 pubic method of same class Caller1() and Caller2(). While writing unit test for these two methods I cannot mock DoSomething() since its private, but this method code will be tested two times.
   How to write code/test in such scenarios?
3. There is a public method DoSomething() which is being called form another public method Caller(). DoSomething() initialize a private member which is then used inside Caller(). I can mock DoSomething() while testing Caller() but wont be able to set data in the private member.
   How to write code/test in this scenarios?

I will update more scenarios in case I face any.

Comment: Described scenario is not TDD  - because in TDD you don't have private methods or private variables. You start writing tests for public API of unit without knowing about it's implementation. You will create private methods and variables during refactoring of already working and tested implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> There is a public method say Initialize(), it initializes only private
>   members of class. How to test this method if it is working fine or
>   not.

You write tests for other public methods, in the test you call `Initialize` method before calling actual method you are testing and assert that other public methods work properly. Tests should fail when `Initialize` method not called or it's implementation is wrong.

> There is a private method say DoSomething() and is being called by 2
>   pubic method of same class Caller1() and Caller2(). While writing unit
>   test for these two methods I cannot mock DoSomething() since its
>   private, but this method code will be tested two times. How to write
>   code/test in such scenarios?

With TDD - test first approach, you shouldn't have private method `DoSomething`. You write tests for both methods `Caller1` and `Caller2`, then when all required tests pass you notice that implementation have some duplication and refactor it by introducing private method `DoSomething`. It's implementation tested twice - it is ok you will have "double safety net".

> There is a public method DoSomething() which is being called form
>   another public method Caller(). DoSomething() initialize a private
>   member which is then used inside Caller(). I can mock DoSomething()
>   while testing Caller() but wont be able to set data in the private
>   member. How to write code/test in this scenarios?

Same as in first case. You call both methods in the test and assert that `Caller` method work properly. Your test will fail if `Initialize` method not called or it's implementation is wrong.

Comment: So in short if any code is reused then it will be retested. And if there is no way to verify the result of a method(no return type and no public member modified) then simply just test it via another method.

Comment: One more thing have to ask... is it appreciated to mock a public method which is being called from a the method which is under test and are in same class?

Comment: I will not suggest to do it. Tests should provide possibility to change internal logic without changing tests. This not always work - but you should aim there.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 laws in TDD:

> 1. You are not allowed to write any production code without first writing a test that fails because the production code does not exist.
> 2. You are not allowed to write more of a test than is sufficient to fail; including failure of compilation.
> 3. You are notallowed to write more production code than is sufficient to pass the currently failing test.

The cycle which is around laws is RED-GREEN-REFACTOR and one of main ideas is discover your production code through multiple simple use cases (test)

If we follow laws:

1. (RED) We wrote the first use case and we name our class and method as we want it to be named and that's you expect

Example:

```
var foo = new Foo()
expect(foo.initialize()).toEqual(false)
```

2. (RED) We launch the test, but we can not! Maybe, the IDE says us (hum, I don't know this class) So we create the class and the method
3. (GREEN) We write the minimum of code to do pass our test. The code can be very ugly! the goal of this step is to pass the test after we have refactoring step

Example:

```
class Foo {
  initialize() {
    return false
  }
}
```

4. (REFACTOR) Immediatly after the green test we refactor our production code
5. (REFACTOR) We launch tests again ; if it's green everything is good. It's red, we check the refactoring. And go back to 1 until the feature is complete.

Why it's so important to refactor every time? Because we refactor the code that we just wrote. We know what it does.

So, during the refactor phase it's here that's you discover if you need private method. If you have it, the test launching at the step 5 checks it implicitly.

You can read those articles: http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/07/SymmetryBreaking.html and http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html

There are many good content about TDD: you can watch videos with Ian Cooper or Uncle Bob (Robert C. Martin)

Comment: These principles are totally correct, but when you work with existing written code where you already have some methods to do some stuff, and you have to reuse it and add new methods then in such case I got stuck in these scenarios. btw Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Can you clarify this point in your question? Because I did not understand that you want to test on the existing code. It's another technique to do this. I will update my answer

Comment: I guess @fabio answer are quite reasonable and to the point for this particular question.